# Why doesn't this decimal32 value have the expected bit pattern?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to deconstruct a 32-bit decimal floating point value in GCC (7.4.0) on an amd64 box, but I'm not getting the expected result. I've followed the description at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal32_floating-point_format and have verified the code at https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libdecnumber

But for some reason, I keep getting weird results:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

static uint8_t exponent_msbs[] =
{
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 255, 255
};

static uint8_t coefficient_msbs[] =
{
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
    8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 255, 255
};


static void print_bits(uint32_t value)
{
    printf("Binary:    ");
    for(int i = 31; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%d", (value>>i)&1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

#define shift_sign 31
#define shift_combination 26
#define width_combination 5
#define shift_exponent 20
#define width_exponent 6
#define width_coefficient 20
#define bias 101

static const uint32_t mask_combination = (1<<width_combination) - 1;
static const uint32_t mask_exponent = (1<<width_exponent) - 1;
static const uint32_t mask_coefficient = (1<<width_coefficient) - 1;


void print_decimal32(_Decimal32 dvalue)
{
    uint32_t uvalue = 0;
    memcpy((uint8_t*)&uvalue, (uint8_t*)&dvalue, sizeof(uvalue));

    uint32_t combination = (uvalue>>shift_combination) & mask_combination;
    uint32_t sign = uvalue>>shift_sign;
    uint32_t exponent_hi = exponent_msbs[combination];
    uint32_t coefficient_hi = coefficient_msbs[combination];
    uint32_t exponent_lo = (uvalue>>shift_exponent)&mask_exponent;
    uint32_t coefficient_lo = uvalue & mask_coefficient;

    int32_t exponent = (exponent_hi << width_exponent) + exponent_lo - bias;
    uint32_t coefficient =  (coefficient_hi << width_coefficient) + coefficient_lo;

    printf("Hex:       %08x\n", uvalue);
    print_bits(uvalue);
    printf("s %x, comb %x, eh %x, el %x, ch %x, cl %x, e %x, c %x\n",
        sign, combination, exponent_hi, exponent_lo,
        coefficient_hi, coefficient_lo, exponent, coefficient);
    printf("Result: %d x 10^%d\n", coefficient, exponent);
}

#define PRINT_DECIMAL32(VALUE) \
    printf("Decimal32: " #VALUE "\n"); \
    print_decimal32(VALUE)

int main()
{
    PRINT_DECIMAL32(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Running this produces the following output:

```
Decimal32: 1
Hex:       32800001
Binary:    00110010100000000000000000000001
s 0, comb c, eh 1, el 28, ch 4, cl 1, e 3, c 400001
Result: 4194305 x 10^3
```

So the exponent is off by 3, and the coefficient MSB is 4 instead of 0. Have I missed something?

Edit: To be clear, the decimal float value `1` in BOTH DPD and BID, should be encoded as `0 [01 000] 100101 00000000000000000001` (0x22500001). The exponent should be 0 (after subtracting 101 bias), and the coefficient should be 1 (not 0x400001).

Comment: Are you sure the value is encoded using DPD encoding? And not the wikis "Binary integer significand field" ? Following the wiki `If the first two bits after the sign bit are "00", "01", or "10", then those are the leading bits of the exponent, and the three bits after that are interpreted as the leading decimal digit (0 to 7):` , then `uint32_t three_bits_after_the_two_bits_after_sign_bit = (uvalue >> (32 - 6)) & 0b111;` is 4. And this is the most significant digit from the true_significand, ie. `true_significant = three_bits... * 1000000 + declets`. And true_significand should be zero here.

Comment: If I follow Binary integer significand field, then I get correct result of `+1 * 10^(101 - 101) * 1`

Comment: Also in DPD the exponent is: two bits after the sign are the leading bits of the exponent, which are joined with the 6 bits from the exponent, ie. here: `(0b01 << 6) | 0b101000 = 0b0110000 = 104`, which is minus bias (101), so the real exponent is 3. Exponent should be zero. Fro DPD I only get `+0 * 10^3 * 1` While the binary integer field works for even numbers like 1234567890 (the number gets encoded as `+0 * 10^3 * 1234568 `, which i guess is good enough).

Comment: Yes, but the answer is still incorrect. The value breaks down to `0 [01 100] 101000 00000000000000000001`, so you have a raw exponent of `01101000` (104). Subtract the bias (101) and you're left with 3, which is not equal to the `0` required for the decimal float value `1`. Furthermore, the significand value `10000000000000000000001` (400001) is also not equal to the decimal value `1` in DPD or BID.

Comment: Then, are you sure the value is encoded using DPD encoding? Why do you think the DPD encoding is used? Is there a gcc switch or something?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether DPD or BID is being used. Both encode the decimal value `1` to the exact same bit pattern. The significand of the value `1` does not become `0x400001` in any interpretation of the standard.

Comment: `Both encode the decimal value 1 to the exact same bit pattern` are you sure about that? Do you have some reference? My paper and pen and wiki got me `0b0 01 000 100101 000..1` for DPD and `0b0 01 100 101000 00000.....1` for BID.

Comment: Oh hang on, I was reading the spec wrong, expecting the shifted exponent and coefficient MSBs to operate the same way in both DPD and BID, when they are actually adjacent in BID, so you are correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.

```
static const uint32_t mask_combination = (2<<width_combination) - 1;
static const uint32_t mask_exponent = (2<<width_exponent) - 1;
static const uint32_t mask_coefficient = (2<<width_coefficient) - 1;
```

These are invalid. The `mask_combination` should be `0b11111`, not `0b111111`. You are doing:

```
(0b10 << 5) - 0b1 =
0b1000000 - 0b1 =
^^^^^^^^^^ this is seven bits, not six
0b111111
^^^^^^^^ - this is six bits, should be 5 for combination
```

You should:

```
static const uint32_t mask_combination = (1<<width_combination) - 1;
static const uint32_t mask_exponent = (1<<width_exponent) - 1;
static const uint32_t mask_coefficient = (1<<width_coefficient) - 1;
```

2. Side note: printing `uint32_t` with `%d` print specifier can be undefined behavior.
3. I will post my code here, maybe it will help others:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static uint8_t exponent_msbs[] =
{
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
    0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 255, 255
};

static uint8_t coefficient_msbs[] =
{
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
    8, 9, 8, 9, 8, 9, 255, 255
};


static void print_bits(const char *pre, 
  uint32_t value, int len, const char *post)
{
  printf("%s", pre);
  for(int i = (len - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%d", (value>>i)&1);
  }
  printf("%s", post);
}

#define shift_sign 31
#define shift_combination 26
#define width_combination 5
#define shift_exponent 20
#define width_exponent 6
#define width_coefficient 20
#define bias 101

static const uint32_t mask_combination = (1<<width_combination) - 1;
static const uint32_t mask_exponent = (1<<width_exponent) - 1;
static const uint32_t mask_coefficient = (1<<width_coefficient) - 1;

void print_decimal32(_Decimal32 dvalue)
{
    uint32_t uvalue = 0;
    memcpy((uint8_t*)&uvalue, (uint8_t*)&dvalue, sizeof(uvalue));

    uint32_t combination = (uvalue>>shift_combination) & mask_combination;
    uint32_t sign = uvalue>>shift_sign;
    uint32_t exponent_hi = exponent_msbs[combination];
    uint32_t coefficient_hi = coefficient_msbs[combination];
    uint32_t exponent_lo = (uvalue>>shift_exponent)&mask_exponent;
    uint32_t coefficient_lo = uvalue & mask_coefficient;

    int32_t exponent = (exponent_hi << width_exponent) + exponent_lo - bias;
    uint32_t coefficient =  (coefficient_hi << width_coefficient) + coefficient_lo;

    printf("Hex:       %08x\n", uvalue);
    print_bits("Binary: ", uvalue, 32, "\n");
    printf("s %x, comb %x, eh %x, el %x, ch %x, cl %x, e %x, c %x\n",
        sign, combination, exponent_hi, exponent_lo,
        coefficient_hi, coefficient_lo, exponent, coefficient);
    printf("Result: %d x 10^%d\n", coefficient, exponent);
}

void BIS_print_decimal32(_Decimal32 dvalue)
{
    uint32_t uvalue = 0;
    // static_assert(sizeof(_Decimal32) == sizeof(uint32_t), "");
    memcpy(&uvalue, &dvalue, sizeof(uvalue));

    uint32_t sign = (uvalue >> 31) & 1;
    uint32_t combination = (uvalue >> (20 + 6)) & 0b11111;
    uint32_t exponent = (uvalue >> (20)) & 0b111111;
    uint32_t coefficient = uvalue & 0b111111111111111111;

    // binary integer significant field
    uint32_t two_bits_after_the_sign_bit = (uvalue >> (32 - 3)) & 3;
    uint32_t significand = 0;
    // If the 2 bits after the sign bit are "00", "01", or "10",
    if (two_bits_after_the_sign_bit != 0b11) {
        // then the exponent field consists of the 8 bits following the sign bit,
        exponent = (uvalue >> (32 - 9)) & 0xff;
        exponent -= 101;
        // and the significand is the remaining 23 bits, with an implicit leading 0 bit: 
        significand = uvalue & 0b111111111111111111111;
    } else {
        // TODO:
        assert(0);
        abort();
        // If the 2 bits after the sign bit are "11", 
        // then the 8-bit exponent field is shifted 2 bits to the right
        // (after both the sign bit and the "11" bits thereafter), 
        // and the represented significand is in the remaining 21 bits. 
        // In this case there is an implicit (that is, not stored) leading 3-bit sequence "100" 
        // in the true significand. 
    }

    // TODO: handle NAN and INF
    uint32_t four_bits_after_the_sign_bit = (uvalue >> (32 - 5)) & 0xf;
    if (four_bits_after_the_sign_bit == 0b1111) {
        assert(0);
        abort();
    }

    printf("value = %+d * 10^%d * %d\n",
        (int)sign,
        (int)exponent,
        (int)significand
    );
}

int declet_to_decimal(uint32_t declet) {
    uint32_t b3 = (declet >> 3) & 1;
    if (b3 == 0) {
        uint32_t b9b8b7 = (declet >> 7) & 0b111;
        uint32_t b6b5b4 = (declet >> 4) & 0b111;
        uint32_t b2b1b0 = (declet >> 0) & 0b111;
        return b9b8b7 * 100 + b6b5b4 * 10 + b2b1b0;
    }
    // TODO: Densely packed decimal encoding rules[4]
    assert(0);
    abort();
    return 0;
}

void DPD_print_decimal32(_Decimal32 dvalue)
{
    uint32_t uvalue = 0;
    // static_assert(sizeof(_Decimal32) == sizeof(uint32_t), "");
    memcpy(&uvalue, &dvalue, sizeof(uvalue));

    uint32_t sign = (uvalue >> 31) & 1;
    uint32_t combination = (uvalue >> (20 + 6)) & 0b11111;
    uint32_t exponent = (uvalue >> (20)) & 0b111111;
    uint32_t coefficient = uvalue & 0b111111111111111111;

    // TODO: handle NAN and INF
    uint32_t four_bits_after_the_sign_bit = (uvalue >> (32 - 5)) & 0xf;
    if (four_bits_after_the_sign_bit == 0b1111) {
        assert(0);
        abort();
    }

    // Densely packed decimal significand field
    uint32_t two_bits_after_the_sign_bit = (uvalue >> (32 - 3)) & 3;
    uint32_t leading_decimal_digit = 0;
    // If the 2 bits after the sign bit are "00", "01", or "10",
    if (two_bits_after_the_sign_bit != 0b11) {
        // If the first two bits after the sign bit are "00", "01", or "10", 
        // then those are the leading bits of the exponent,
        exponent = (two_bits_after_the_sign_bit << 6) | exponent;
        exponent -= 101;
        // and the three bits after that are interpreted as the leading decimal digit (0 to 7):
        uint32_t three_bits_after_the_two_bits_after_sign_bit = (uvalue >> (32 - 6)) & 0b111; 
        leading_decimal_digit = three_bits_after_the_two_bits_after_sign_bit;
        printf("leading_decimal_digit: %d\n", leading_decimal_digit);
    } else {
        // TODO:
        assert(0);
        abort();
    }

    uint32_t significand = coefficient;
    uint32_t declet1 = (significand >> 10) & 0b1111111111;
    uint32_t declet2 = significand & 0b1111111111;

    uint32_t decimal1 = declet_to_decimal(declet1);
    uint32_t decimal2 = declet_to_decimal(declet2);

    uint32_t truesignificand = 
        leading_decimal_digit * 1000000 + 
        decimal1 * 1000 + 
        decimal2;


    printf("value = %+d * 10^%d * %d\n",
        (int)sign,
        (int)exponent,
        (int)truesignificand
    );
}

#define PRINT_DECIMAL32(VALUE)  do{ \
    printf("==> Decimal32: " #VALUE " <== \n"); \
    print_decimal32(VALUE); \
    printf("# BIS_print_decimal32\n"); \
    BIS_print_decimal32(VALUE); \
    printf("# DPD_print_decimal32\n"); \
    DPD_print_decimal32(VALUE); \
    printf("\n\n"); \
    }while(0)

int main()
{
    PRINT_DECIMAL32(1);
    PRINT_DECIMAL32(2);
    PRINT_DECIMAL32(3);
    return 0;
}
```

4. After some experimentation with gcc implementation, gcc uses the ["Binary integer significand field"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal32_floating-point_format) format and not the "Densely packed decimal significand field" format. And this is the reason your calculations are incorrect. I could not find however any reference or documentation about that, so it is based upon empirical data. If future readers find a reference that assures that gcc uses this implementation for _Decimal32 numbers, be free to edit this post.

Comment: Whoops! You're right, but the incorrect masks weren't actually affecting the result in this case. I'll update the question, but the result is still the same :/

Comment: regarding: `if (two_bits_after_the_sign_bit != 11) {`   This is testing a 3 bit field for the value 11 (0x1011)  This is not correct.  Suggest: `two_bits_after_the_sign_bit & 0x03`

Comment: @user3629249 Nice, thanks. It's a typo,  I meant to use the `0b` gcc extension and write `0b11`.